# How can you make a Git directory or file read only?

Tags: git, file

I want to add my Photoshop documents (PSDs) to the repo. However, I want to be the only person who can edit/push the files and all others can read. The reason is that the developers know enough Photoshop to use the documents to get values (font size, colors, etc...) but I don't want them to accidentally edit a file and commit it.

Or maybe there is another way all together?

Comment: Tell them "Never commit PSDs!". You should have at least a little trust in your colleagues ;) On the other hand the number one reason to use a vcs is, that you always can revert changes. So even if they accidentally commit one of "your" files nothing is lost. Oh, and worth to say: You may left the company one day, or simply go on vacation. Leaving your team alone with files they cannot change when required is a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for saying "on vacation" instead of "brutally dragged down the road under a bus". These are good thoughts. I will try the verbal warning solution and see how long it lasts :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the PSD files in a different repo where they only have pull access.

You can not set access rights within the repo using git.

Comment: I thought of this but it sucks because I am also developing (code) in the same repo and it is a minor pain to switch. However, it isn't THAT hard I guess. Thanks!