# How to prevent developers from committing into certain folders of git repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

How to prevent developers from committing into certain folders of git repository which they don't own. Is there a way to prevent this using permissions on gitlab, since we want to enforce that certain folders (say folderA, folderB) are writable but folderC only is viewable.

Comment: Closing parenthesis is misplaced (should be after "folderB") and there's a possibility of confusion at the end of the sentence : is it "**only** folderC is viewable" or "folderC is **only viewable**"?

Comment: Looks like the duplicate of the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968512/how-can-you-make-a-git-directory-or-file-read-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you make a Git directory or file read only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968512/how-can-you-make-a-git-directory-or-file-read-only)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible on GitLab through the Code owners feature: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/code_owners.html

Take into account that this is a premium feature.